# How to underline a TextBlock on a MouseEnter

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF form, I have the following TextBlock. When I move my mouse over it, I would like to see the text of the TextBlock underlined. How can I do that? I tried with TextBlock.Triggers, but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a style:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hurrah">
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

(Style shown inline for brevity; extract into a resource if you're planning to reuse it.)

Comment: This was really helpful. But what if I need to underline just the first character?

Comment: @conqenator: Then you would need to break out the differently-formatted bits into multiple inlines: `<TextBlock><Run Style="...">H</Run>urrah</TextBlock>` and apply the style to the Run instead of the TextBlock (as shown).  The style would be the same except a TargetType of Run; and you'd definitely want to extract it into a resource because writing it inline it would swamp the readability of the XAML!