# Underline a group of textblocks or inlines

Tags: c#, wpf

Short version: I would like to underline anything underlineable that sits inside a DependencyObject, eg in this case I can set Font size and colour but I cannot set it to be underlined:

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.Foreground="Red" Inline.TextDecorations="Underline">
    <TextBlock Text="This ">
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock><Run Text="is "></Run><Run Text="a test"></Run></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

So how can I specify on one location that I would like all of the text underlined?

Long Version: I am creating a hyperlink control that works like a ContentPresenter. The programmer using my hyperlink control can place content into the control and specify a DataTemplate to present their content. On MouseOver I want a trigger to set the font to red and underline the text. I can get it to change the colour to red very easily but the underlining is proving to be an issue.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Inline.TextDecorations" Value="Underline"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ContentHyperlink}}, Path=ActiveColor}"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484072/underline-label-in-wpf-using-styles check out this question and see if it meets your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That appears to be the same question. Who would have thought it would be so hard? I have just done it in c# code which is not ideal but is working well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link posted in the comments it looks like there might not be a good xaml way to do this. I am currently using C# code and it works well enough. For the benefit of the community here is my solution. Any comments on ways to do this better are welcome. I just trap the MouseLeave and MouseEnter events and show the underline there.

```
    void Control_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WPFHelper.EnumerateChildren<TextBlock>(this, true).ForEach(c => c.TextDecorations = null);
    }

    void Control_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WPFHelper.EnumerateChildren<TextBlock>(this, true).ForEach(c => c.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline);
    }
```

The WPFHelper class simply enumerates all the children of a DependencyObject and ForEach is an extension method that just executes the action inside the lambda expression for each item.